# How to add the Audio/Video Property tab to Caja?

Tags: mate-desktop

By default Caja does not come with the Audio/Video Properties tab that is present in Nautilus since... a very long time.

How can this tab be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gnome-mplayer` includes an extension for caja since version `1.0.9-2`:

https://code.google.com/p/gnome-mplayer/source/checkout

However, the version of `gnome-mplayer-1.0.9-2` that comes from the Ubuntu repositories does not include the caja extension:

`/usr/lib/caja/extensions-2.0/libgnome-mplayer-caja-properties-page.so`

OR (for amd64):

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/caja/extensions-2.0/libgnome-mplayer-caja-properties-page.so`

I suspect that the reason is that when the .DEB was compiled, caja was not installed and thus not detected.

Therefore the only solution is to compile from source or use a deb compiled by someone else:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x340ym3xeyhuosu/gnome-mplayer_1.0.9.2-2_amd64.deb?dl=1
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qm6nkgkaebddtrj/gnome-mplayer_1.0.9-1_i386.deb?dl=1

STEPS to compile:

1. Install dependencies:

Run the following as root:

```
apt-get build-dep gnome-mplayer
apt-get install make automake
apt-get install svn
apt-get install libcaja-extension-dev
```

2. Download source code with svn:

`svn checkout http://gnome-mplayer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gnome-mplayer`

3. Compile

The `make` might complain that it cannot find `automake-1.13` when you have `automake-1.14`
In order to resolve this run the following in the source folder:

```
aclocal
automake
./configure
make
```

after this all you need to do is to run:
`make install` OR `checkinstall`

Finally you might need to also install `mplayer` if you don't already have it.
Restart `caja` by logout/login or `killall caja`

Now you should have the property tab.
If you don't, check if you can open a movie with gnome-mplayer.

Let me know if you encounter any issues!

UPDATE: referenced dropbox package now installs the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

sorry for waking up this post but not so easy to find 'new' info:

## apt install caja-media-info

now do the job.

Tks.